# MFP 6.3 - WL.Client.makeRequest - Deprecated

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mfp

`WL.Client.makeRequest()` the function is deprecated in MFP 8.0. What are the uses of the function? If any document you have please share with me.

What is the correct solution for this In MFP 8.0

After Run migration command `mfpmigrate scan`. I am getting like this

```
Create a custom adapter that provides the same functionality
```

Please given any document related the function and what the alternative solution in MFP 8.0

Thanks,
Karthik S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WL.Client.makeRequest()` API allowed making outbound calls to endpoints.

In MFP 8.0, you should use `WLResourceRequest` API instead. API documentation [here](http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/api-ref/wl-client-js-apidoc/html/refjavascript-client/html/WLResourceRequest.html).

Answer (score 2):

> **WL.Client.makeRequest()** the function is deprecated in MFP 8.0

In IBM MobileFirst Foundation 8.0, You have to install **mfpdev-cli** & **cordova-plugin-mfp** then use **WLResourceRequest**. see the sample:

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
    "/adapters/JavaAdapter/users",
    WLResourceRequest.GET
);
var formParams = {"param1": "value1", "param2": "value2"};
resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(formParams);

resourceRequest.send().then(
    onSuccess,
    onFailure
)
```

I suggest that you will take a tour of the MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 migration from Earlier Releases . See here:

Migrating from Earlier Releases: http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/

Migrating existing Cordova and hybrid applications: http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/upgrading/migrating-client-applications/cordova/#starting-the-cordova-app-migration-with-the-migration-assistance-tool

> Create a custom adapter that provides the same functionality

Take a tour of how to create custom adapter in IBM MobileFirst 8.0: http://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/adapters/creating-adapters/

Comment: Gaurab Kumar, Thanks for the solution. I know about MFP 8.0. But I don't know the correct replacement of the makeRequest(). Now I understand the WLResourceRequest is the correct replacement of makeRequest. Thanks.